# Allow users to edit account details to Postgres in Django in a Class-based View

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

I've spent ages trying to figure out how to allow a user of my website to edit their account details. I've tried a ton of options, but none seem to be working. All my views are currently class-based, and any function based views haven't worked.

I'm using Django's pre-built User model, and my database used is PostgreSQL. currently my homepage can navigate to the user's account page (If logged in, otherwise sends them to the login page), where there is a link to update_user.html. But from there I'm not sure how to either use a html form to send data to a python script, or use a Django form to collect the data to start with, nor how to write the code for that to work. Any advice? Many thanks

EDIT: Some examples of what I've tried:

html form collecting the logged in user's data and presenting it in the textfields:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit Account</h1>


<form action="{% url 'edit_user' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2> Username:</h2><input type="text" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}">  <br />
    <h2>First Name</h2> <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ user.first_name }}">  <br />
    <h2>Last Name</h2> <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{ user.last_name }}"/>  <br />
    <h2> Email: </h2><input type="textarea" name="email" value="{{ user.email }}">  <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ user.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

In addition to this function, which has been tested to work in submitting data:

```
            database_connector = psycopg2.connect('dbname=CajoIA user=postgres host=localhost password=my_password')
            database_cursor = database_connector.cursor()
            database_cursor.execute('UPDATE auth_user SET username = %s, first_name = %s, last_name = %s, email = %s WHERE id = %s'%(username, first_name, last_name, email, id))
            database_connector.commit()
            database_cursor.close()
            username = database_cursor.execute('SELECT username FROM auth_user WHERE id = %s'%(id))
            edit_account_details(username, first_name, last_name, email, id)
```

The trouble I've had is how to link these two together, as in, how can I make the text inputted by the user be saved and put into the function

I've also tried several class-based and function based ideas which have resulted in unfunctioning links and pages. I could post them too if neccisary, but I'be spend at this point dozens of hours trying to find an answer, and hence dozens of solutions, so it's take a long time to post them all. Looking for a simple way to allow the use to change their user details in django

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried with along with any error if you got.

Comment: @ans2human Just did. Thanks!!